# How can I prevent BitLocker asking for recovery key every time?

Tags: bitlocker

Recently when I tried to boot Windows, BitLocker asked me to enter the recovery key every single time after I entered the PIN. My machine is a Fujitsu Lifebook E547, which uses UEFI with Secure Boot and TPM both enabled, with the default boot entry being GRUB2 from which I loaded Windows Boot Manager.

I tried suspending and resuming BitLocker but it didn't fix the problem.
I then disabled BitLocker. When I tried to enable it, the system check failed because "The data drive specified is not set to automatically unlock on the current computer and cannot be unlocked automatically. C: was not encrypted."
I tried resetting the TPM in the UEFI configuration, and the result was the same.
If I bypass the system check, after rebooting it told me to enter the recovery key again.

How can I set up BitLocker to operate normally?

Comment: Whatever else you do, **be sure you have a complete disk image** before changing BitLocker. There are **many** posts here asking what to do after BitLocker issues, and the vast majority of answers boil down to, "Nothing can be recovered."

Comment: If you disabled BitLocker that means you decrypted the entire storage device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this happened either after you installed Linux or after you upgraded grub and this is caused by sealing the decryption key by various system hashes and changing them by one of the above.

There is a full readout here: [Windows Vista - BitLocker Error - "system boot information has changed"](http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2007/11/windows-vista-bitlocker-error-system.html).

In short, you have two options (please note I don't remember all the details, your mileage may vary):

1. Suspend bitlocker, reboot, re-enable (if needed). This will force re-sealing the key and should fix your immediate issue. In the future, suspend bitlocker before upgrading grub or installing other OS along the Windows.
2. Don't seal the key with anything but PCR11 (that's the bare minimum required, allowing some others might work but you'd need to experiment). This can be changed by gpedit.msc (see linked article for details) and should make the previous steps unnecessary.

**MAKE SURE AT EACH STEP TO CHECK THAT RECOVERY KEY DIDN'T CHANGE ALONG THE WAY BEFORE REBOOTING WINDOWS!**